# React Form Not Fetching From Express Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have a express backend that makes a GET request to the OpenWeather API when a POST request is made from a React form. Currently, the problem lies in the backend POST route I believe not calling correctly and unable to store the search term. When I was debugging, I made a fetch request from the front end which works and I also put in a dummy array stored in express using the same route that's not working and that is able to be fetched from the front and backend.

No POST requests show up in the network tab, only GET requests with a response of 304 but in the console I receive "cod: "400", message: "bad query" which I'm assuming is the error message from the OpenWeather API

**REACT CODE**

```
const WeatherContainer = () => {
    let [searchTerm, setsearchTerm] = useState('')
    let [currentWeather, setCurrentWeather] = useState({});
    let [forecastedWeather, setForecastedWeather] = useState({});
    let [loading, setLoading] = useState(false); 
    
    const handleInput = (e) => {
        setsearchTerm(e.target.value);
    }

    const handleSearch = () => {
        fetch('/search-weather')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                    setCurrentWeather({data})
                    console.log(data)
               })
    };
    

    return (
        <>
            <div className='search-bar'>
                <form method="POST" action='/search-term'>
                    <input className='text_input' type='text' name='searchTerm' onChange={handleInput} placeholder='Enter city' />
                    <button className='search-button' onClick={handleSearch} type='submit' value='submit' name='button'>
                        <Icon icon={searchIcon} flip="horizontal" />
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
            {}
            <div className='weather_container'>
                <CurrentWeatherComponent />
                <ForecastContainer />
            </div>
        </>
    )

};
```

**EXPRESS CODE**

```
const express = require('express');
const PORT = 5000;
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const app = express();
//const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const weatherApiKey = '****HIDDEN****';
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(express.static("client"));
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

let searchTerm;

// Post From Input, Route uses 'searchTerm' name attribute in input
app.post('/search-term', (req, res) => {
    searchTerm = req.body.searchTerm;
    
});

// GET Current & Forecast Weather By Search Term
app.get('/search-weather', (req, res) => {

    const currentUrl = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${searchTerm}&units=imperial&appid=${weatherApiKey}`;

    fetch(currentUrl)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(currentData => {
            return res.json({currentData})
        })
        .catch(err => { 
            res.redirect('/error')
    });  
}); 


app.listen(PORT); 
console.log(`Server is listening on ${PORT}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably in the body of your Search Weather callback, the "${searchTerm}" is undefined. So you set the "q" param as "undefined", that's why you got bad query.

I've checked that for me with test token and got that too (for empty terms).
Here's [Working](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=madrid&units=imperial&appid=01c2dab301eeeff7e02ebf1748f65faa) & [Bad query](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=undefined&units=imperial&appid=01c2dab301eeeff7e02ebf1748f65faa)

Comment: searchTerm is declared globally above the POST route, so would that mean my post route is not posting and therefore the search term is never stored in the variable to be used in the GET request?

Comment: Nope, that are different requests, so each request holds their different "instances" (not mean the Node instance) of your app. The GET request knows nothing about previous POST request. You can store that previous value somewhere in the DB or with another way. Anyway the reason is that

Comment: It will be better to send the search term with the GET request as an additional param

Comment: how would I do that exactly @boolfalse

Comment: I'm not very well in React, but if you're sending that data (after submit the form) from front to back successfully, then probably you can get that like "req.body.searchTerm". So you can use that retrieved value

Comment: I figured it out using your help @boolfalse , check out my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, my POST was not working for whatever reason so I combined the search term parameter from the input field into the GET request and now my Express proxy server communicates correctly to the OpenWeatherAPI, retrieves the results, then sends the results back to the client. I used route parameters, which you can read more about [here](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters).

**REFORMATED REACT CODE**

```
const WeatherContainer = () => {
    let [searchTerm, setsearchTerm] = useState('')
    let [currentWeather, setCurrentWeather] = useState({});
    let [forecastedWeather, setForecastedWeather] = useState({});
    let [loading, setLoading] = useState(false); 
    
    const handleInput = (e) => {
        setsearchTerm(e.target.value);
    }

    const handleSearch = () => {
        fetch(`/weather/${searchTerm}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                    console.log(data)
               })
    };
    

    return (
        <>
            <div className='search-bar'>
                    <input className='text_input' type='text' name='searchTerm' onChange={handleInput} placeholder='Enter city' />
                    <button className='search-button' onClick={handleSearch} type='submit' value='submit' name='button'>
                        <Icon icon={searchIcon} flip="horizontal" />
                    </button>
            </div>
            
            <div className='weather_container'>
                <CurrentWeatherComponent />
                <ForecastContainer />
            </div>
        </>
    )

};
```

**REFORMATED EXPRESS CODE**

```
const express = require('express');
const PORT = 5000;
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const app = express();
const weatherApiKey = '***HIDDEN***';
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(express.static("client"));
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// GET Current & Forecast Weather By Search Term
app.get('/weather/:searchTerm', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params)
    const searchTerm = req.params.searchTerm;
    console.log(searchTerm)
    
    let currentUrl = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${searchTerm}&units=imperial&appid=${weatherApiKey}`;
  
    fetch(currentUrl)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            res.send(data)
        })
        .catch(err => { 
            res.redirect('/error')
    });  
}); 


app.listen(PORT); 
console.log(`Server is listening on ${PORT}`);
```

[image: Network Request / Console of Data]

[image: Server console showing the search query]